# If distance correlation $DCOR(X,Y) = 0.5$ then are X and Y dependent or independent?

Tags: probability, independence, probability-inequalities, distance-covariance

If distance correlation $DCOR(X,Y) = 0.5$ then are $X$ and $Y$ statistically dependent or independent? What about when $DCOR(X,Y) > 0$, are they statistically dependent for sure even when it's less than 1? If distance covariance $DCOV(X,Y) > 0$ then are $X, Y$ surely statistically dependent?

By distance correlation am referring to the one introduced by Szekely, et.al.

Comment: Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation , which references Székely, "In statistics and in probability theory, distance correlation is a measure of statistical dependence between two random variables or two random vectors of arbitrary, not necessarily equal dimension. An important property is that this measure of dependence is zero if and only if the random variables are statistically independent."

Comment: @Mark L. Stone So $X,Y$ are statistically dependent if and only if $DCOR(X,Y) > 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, because DCOR(X,Y) must be $\ge$ 0.

Comment: $\ge 0$ or $> 0$? Just confirming!

Comment: DCOR(X,Y) must be ≥ 0. Therefore, X,Y are statistically dependent if and only if DCOR(X,Y) > 0.   X,Y are statistically independent if and only if DCOR(X,Y) = 0.

Comment: Note though that in most cases you'll just have an estimate of DCOR, not the true value. In that case, distinguishing whether a given estimate is consistent with a true distance correlation of 0 or not is another problem.